# What is the correct way to validate password in PHP 5.4?

Tags: php

I just recently found out that `password_verify($string, $hash)` only works for 5.5 and above.

I am therefore looking for the correct way to do it in 5.4?

Comment: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/472495).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read further through the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for the PHP 5.5 password functions, you'll find reference to a [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) that can act as a plug-in replacement for PHP >= 5.3.7